# Configure multiple interfaces with DHCP on CentOS

Tags: centos, networking, dhcp, iproute

I am trying to get a DHCP-assigned address for a `veth` device (`veth-inside`) inside of a network namespace (`myns`) on CentOS 7, but `dhclient` is already running. The `veth` peer device (`veth-outside`) is in the default namespace, bridged to the physical network interface (`ens3`).

The devices in the default namespace were configured as follows:

```
(cent7)$ ip link add name br0 type bridge
(cent7)$ ip link add name veth-inside type veth peer name veth-outside
(cent7)$ ip link set dev ens3 master br0
(cent7)$ ip link set dev ens3 up
(cent7)$ ip link set dev veth-outside master br0
(cent7)$ ip link set dev veth-outside up
(cent7)$ ip link set dev br0 up
(cent7)$ dhclient br0
```

`br0` obtains 192.168.0.5 (via DHCP reservation) as expected. Then, the network namespace and `veth-inside` peer device are configured, but `dhclient` returns nonzero, with the following:

```
(cent7)$ ip netns add myns
(cent7)$ ip link set dev veth-inside netns myns
(cent7)$ ip netns exec myns ip link set dev veth-inside up
(cent7)$ ip netns exec myns dhclient veth-inside
dhclient(29674) is already running - exiting. 

(cent7)$ dhclient --version
isc-dhclient-4.2.5
```

---

All of the above works flawlessly on Ubuntu 14.04. I can use `dhclient` to assign IP addresses to any number of physical, virtual, or bridge devices at will on Ubuntu, whether they are in the default namespace, or isolated in their own `netns`.

```
(ub1404)$ dhclient --version
isc-dhclient-4.2.4
```

Also, I have uninstalled `NetworkManager` from the CentOS system, and have disabled `NetworkManager` for the bridge and physical devices on the Ubuntu system, so NM is not involved with these network devices in any way.

How can I assign IP addresses via DHCP to multiple, arbitrary interfaces in CentOS 7? Is `dhclient` somehow configured or built differently on CentOS than on Ubuntu, such that multiple invocations of it is disallowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run multiple instances of `dhclient` you can use the `--no-pid` on each invocation. Redhat's version of dhclient is modified, so that might explain the difference between ubuntu and centos in this regard.

Make the following changes to your dhclient arguments:

```
dhclient --no-pid br0
ip netns exec myns dhclient --no-pid veth-inside
```

Now each instance should be blissfully unaware of each other.

Others should note that this could cause problems for different configurations, so this solution should only be considered if you know what you're doing!

Comment: @scottbb I see. You might try passing the `--no-pid` option so that it doesn't complain about other instances running. If this works I'll edit the answer

Comment: @scottbb did you specify `dhclient --no-pid br0` also? This eliminates the error on my end

Comment: Boom! That was it. Done, upvoted, and accepted.

Comment: @scottbb awesome, glad it's working. I've updated the answer to reflect this solution